# InflateException: Binary XML file

Tags: android, fragment, android-inflate

this is the error that i've got

```
12-05 13:26:18.102: E/AndroidRuntime(10101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 13:26:18.102: E/AndroidRuntime(10101): Process: com.example.project_1_4, PID: 10101
12-05 13:26:18.102: E/AndroidRuntime(10101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         
ComponentInfo{com.example.project_1_4/          
com.example.project_1_4.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14:     
Error inflating class fragment
```

my xml file - i think i missed bracket when i was posting. now i correct it.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="410dp" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

source code

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Dday_fragment extends ListFragment{

    ArrayList<Detail> detailList = new ArrayList<Detail>();
    ArrayList<String> detailName = new ArrayList<String>();
    DetailOperation DetailDBOperation;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = new View(getActivity());
        try{
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dday_fragment, container, false);
        }catch (InflateException e){
        }

        DetailDBOperation = new DetailOperation(null);
        try {
            DetailDBOperation.open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        if(DetailDBOperation.getAllDetail()!=null){
        detailList = DetailDBOperation.getAllDetail();
        }else{
            detailList = null;
        }

        int size = detailList.size();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            detailName.add(detailList.get(i).getSubjectName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, detailName);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Detail_fragment dtf = (Detail_fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.detail_fragment);
        dtf.change(position);
        getListView().setSelector(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
    }

}
```

this is the full code of Dday_fragment.java 
how can i use onListItemClick if i don't use ListFragment?
what i want is to show list of items in dday_fragment, 
and there is another xml that changes with item id which is selected by user.
another xml will shows details of item.
so i used onListItemClick to change and set text on another xml.

Comment: can you please post full xml code of dday_fragment ?

Comment: If you are extending fragment with `LisstFragment` there is no need to use `ListView` in xml file.

Comment: that is full xml code haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `">"` tag for `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
```

another thing is you have inflated view in `onCreateView()` method and also you are trying to create instance of `View` twice so there is problem. No need to do this. So just change

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  try{

     View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dday_fragment, container, false);

  } catch (InflateException e){
  }

  DetailDBOperation = new DetailOperation(getActivity());
  try {
    DetailDBOperation.open();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: at the end of this onCreateView, don't i need to return view? if i do that it says 'view cannnot be resolved as a variable'. 
return view; <---

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your Layout XML file. Make sure you close the brackets which is opened. Here is what you missed.

```
<LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

Alternate way to do this is:

```
<LinearLayout />
```

Comment: accidentally erased i think ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare attribute end enclose. Please do like below :

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="410dp" >
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think its accidentally erased when i was posting.